# Which method of IPython is the Jupyter Notebook executing the Python code in the cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Looking at the source code for the Jupyter Notebook on GitHub, it looks like I'm using IPython to implement the Python interpreter.

I would like to know where in which file the Python code is executed in the source code of Jupyter Notebook.

(Jupyter Notebook seems to send Python code to the server via websocket. That's about it now.)

Comment: I think this question needs more focus, and evidence that you have studied the Jupyter docs.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. I read the Jupyter Docs. I understood that  IPykernel execute  Python code.

https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel

ipykernel/ipkernelbase.py#execute_request -> ipykernel/ipkernel.py#do_execute -> IPython/Core/interactive.py#run_cell

Thank you for teaching me.

Answer (score 1):

As a warning, you *really* do not want to look at how IPython is doing things if you are trying to understand how Python code is executing. We do *extremely* complex things to suport weird features, like top-level async execution.

As you pointed out in your comments, the flow of code is Browser -> Server (via  Websocket) -> IPykernel (via ZMQ) -> IPython.

IPython itself will do a bunch of transforms, and the code `compile/exec` will be [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/770024afeaa5bd66910cf89b9667c4967b65004e/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L3459-L3473)

What you are likely looking for is the [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) and [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), and well as [cmd module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) to write a REPL. I would also strongly recommend looking at [prompt toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/) as a `cmd` replacement.